# SQL Search Query with multiple columns needs to edited

Tags: sql, hql, multiple-columns, wavemaker

I have a search query including one table and two columns.

```
Select * 
from Gecoserv _a 
where _a.typeOfEcosystem IN (:typeNameList) 
    AND _a.service IN (:serviceNameList)
```

It works but it's not giving the result I wanted

Let's say:

```
typeNameList = { Freshwater, Saltwater, Dunes }
serviceNameList = {Habitat, Food, Recreation }
```

I want the grid to show only the single combinations (Freshwater-Habitat, Saltwater-Food and Dunes-Recreation etc.) but it shows also other combinations (ex: Freshwater-Recreation).

In other words : The query results show

```
[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],
[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],
[2,0],[2,1],[2,2].
```

But I want to see ONLY : `[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]`.

I know that I have to add something to the end of query. I tried many things but couldn't figure out a perfect solution.

Is there anybody who can help me with that?

Regards,

Melih

Comment: Do your tables have unique keys (or other identifying columns) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done, when this is the only information you've got. The relation between the values of the parameters, is their position in their list. There is no option to relate and/or preserve these positions in SQL.

What influence do you have on creating the sql-statement?

If you can iterate over the lists in code and dynamically create the sql, you could come to a solution like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Gecoserv 
  WHERE typeOfEcosystem = 'Freshwater' AND service = 'Habitat'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Gecoserv 
  WHERE typeOfEcosystem = 'Freshwater' AND service = 'Food'
UNION
...
```

For an example of how to parameterize this, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/410699).

**An alternative: splitting strings**

Your main problem is to preserve the "rank"/"position" of the parameters in their lists. This can be done, by replacing your lists by strings and break them up.

I used this [example of a splitting a string in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco).

The resulting query (made with [this Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d960c/12)) then looks like:

```
DECLARE 
  @ecoSystems varchar(100) = 'Freshwater,Saltwater,Dunes',
  @services varchar(100) = 'Habitat,Food,Recreation',
  @separator char(1) = ','

SELECT
  [g].[id],
  [g].[typeOfEcoSystem],
  [g].[service]
FROM [dbo].[Split](@separator, @ecoSystems) [e]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Split](@separator, @services) [s] 
  ON [e].[position] = [s].[position]
INNER JOIN [Gecoserv] [g] 
  ON [e].[part] = [g].[typeOfEcoSystem]
    AND [s].[part] = [g].[service]
ORDER BY [id] ASC
```

*Will this work for your scenario?* (Answer: yes, almost...)

**And finally without a function**

```
DECLARE 
  @ecoSystems varchar(100) = 'Freshwater,Saltwater,Dunes',
  @services varchar(100) = 'Habitat,Food,Recreation',
  @separator char(1) = ',';

WITH [EcoSystemsAndServices]([posE], [startE], [endE], [posS], [startS], [endS])
AS 
(
  SELECT 
    1, 
    1, 
    CHARINDEX(@separator, @ecoSystems),
    1, 
    1, 
    CHARINDEX(@separator, @services)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    [posE] + 1, 
    [endE] + 1, 
    CHARINDEX(@separator, @ecoSystems, [endE] + 1),
    [posS] + 1, 
    [endS] + 1, 
    CHARINDEX(@separator, @services, [endS] + 1)
  FROM [EcoSystemsAndServices]
  WHERE [endE] > 0
)


SELECT 
  [g].[id],
  [g].[typeOfEcoSystem],
  [g].[service]
FROM [Gecoserv] [g]
INNER JOIN [EcoSystemsAndServices] [ess] 
  ON [g].[typeOfEcoSystem] = SUBSTRING(@ecoSystems, 
                                        [startE], 
                                        CASE WHEN [endE] > 0 THEN [endE] - [startE] ELSE 100 END)
    AND [g].[service] = SUBSTRING(@services, 
                                  [startS], 
                                  CASE WHEN [endS] > 0 THEN [endS] - [startS] ELSE 100 END)
ORDER BY [id] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I want to do is not writing the elements one by one. The first query you wrote is working great but there should be a way to take elements who have the same rank. (For example: typeNameList[4] and serviceList[4] or typeNameList[28] and serviceList[28]) So, what I'm looking for is the query enables us to select the items from array variables; typeNameList and serviceNameList. But the trick is the elements should have the same rank.

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer. And can you remove your answer, that was meant to be a comment?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, this works for my scenario. But we have a problem. The thing is I have been coding in Wavemaker and I'm using HQL instead of SQL. I thought I could apply by modifying the SQL query on HQL. But I don't know if it is possible to create a function on HQL. I have searched for this, but couldn't find any useful info. Do you have any suggestion in that situation ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wavemaker, neither with HQL. I did manage to write this without using a function. Though this query does not run on SqlFiddle, it does in Sql Server Management Studio. Hope it runs on your environment too...

Comment: Thanks Jacco you really helped me a lot. I haven't figured it out yet on how to appy this in Wavemaker-HQL, but I'm working on it. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I added the tags 'Wavemaker' and 'HQL' to your question, maybe that will attract the appropriate audience. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Without any backing schema or even a database manufacturer, my response will have to make some assumptions about your setup.

**Theory**

This sounds an awful lot like a Cartesian product.  The crux of your problem is that your IN clauses are both independent of one another.  Thus, a single record can satisfy both conditions but not be what you want to see in the result set.  As an example say we have a record as follows:

```
id   name          typeOfEcosystem  service
--   ------------  ---------------  ----------
 1   myEcoService  Freshwater       Recreation
```

Your query, as it is written now, will first take the typeOfEcosystem (Freshwater) and check if it is in your list, which it is.  **Result:  TRUE**

Then, the query will take the service (Recreation) and check if it is in the second list.  Again, the value is found.  **Result:  TRUE**

All conditions evaluate to true, so the row is included in the final result set.

**Solution**

It sounds to me like you want a multiple column IN clause.  Note that this is distinct from your attempt, as the final solution should only involve a single IN keyword.  Now, the exact form of the query will depend a lot on your database and what it provides.  A solution that should work on any SQL-compliant database is to use string manipulation.  A rough example is as follows:

```
Select * 
  from Gecoserv _a 
 where _a.typeOfEcosystem || '-' || _a.service IN ('Freshwater-Habitat', 'Saltwater-Food', 'Dunes-Recreation')
```

In this example, '||' is assumed to be concatenation.  This is very portable, but it is SLOW.  The problem can be tackled much more elegantly, but the exact solution will depend a lot more on your specific database and requirements.  For example, a multiple column in clause in Oracle might be as simple as:

```
Select * 
  from Gecoserv _a 
 where (_a.typeOfEcosystem, _a.service) IN (('Freshwater', 'Habitat'), ('Saltwater', 'Food'), ('Dunes', 'Recreation'));
```

You may have to massage any of these solutions to get them to play well with your DBMS.  Further techniques (and just plain old god reading) can be found at:

1. [SQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause)
2. [Select records where a combinations of columns are repeated using SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430411/select-records-where-a-combinations-of-columns-are-repeated-using-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I want to do is not writing the elements one by one. The first query you wrote is working great but there should be a way to take elements who have the same rank. (For example: typeNameList[4] and serviceList[4] or typeNameList[28] and serviceList[28])
So, what I'm looking for is the query enables us to select the items from array variables; typeNameList and serviceNameList. But the trick is the elements should have the same rank.